# "cross one's mind" and "enter one's mind"

Tags: differences

To my knowledge, both of them imply that someone thinks of something in a short time, but is there any difference between them? For example

> It never crosses my mind that he is lying to me.
>
> It never crosses my mind that we might lose.

I think using **enter my mind** here is fine.

> It never enters my mind that he is lying to me.
>
> It never enters my mind that we might lose.

Comment: Practically speaking, they mean the same thing.  There may be subtle differences in the shades of meaning in certain contexts, but I can't think of any examples.

Comment: BTW, the idiomatic usage (at least in the US) when speaking in the present voice is past tense:  *crossed* or *entered*.

Comment: @Hot Licks: I can't see what you mean. Surely no-one uses ***crossed*** in, say, *When I'm playing poker, it never **crosses** my mind that I might lose.*

Comment: @FumbleFingers - But one would say "It never *crossed* my mind that you would object to my comment."

Comment: @Hot Licks: Yes, but although you might very well says something like that *immediately after* the other person *has in fact objected* (so it has high *relevance* to the present moment), the reality is that you're referring back to the past (*before* you realised, back when you *didn't* think of that possibility).

Comment: @FumbleFingers - But the point is that the idiom is mostly used in "rebuttal" mode, responding to an "accusation":  "You're parked in my parking space again."  "It never crossed my mind that you would be here so early."

Comment: @Hot Licks: Hmm. Maybe you're right, but it's not intuitively obvious to me  that *It never crossed my mind that he'd object* is actually more likely to be said immediately after he objected, rather than when reporting the situation much later.

Comment: (Having said that, if ***you*** were addressee, I think *It never crossed my mind that **you would have objected*** might work a bit better for the "more remote past" context.)

Answer (score 2):

The two verbs '*to cross*' an '*to enter*' are the key here:

> v.tr.
>   1. To go or extend across; pass from one side of to the other: *crossed the room to greet us*

([Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/cross))

The connotations of *cross* are to go in and then out of, in your case, one's mind. Compare this to *enter*:

> v.tr.
>   1. To come or go into: *The train entered the tunnel.*

([Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/enter))

*Enter* simply denotes the going *in* to one's mind and has no such connotation of it being fleeting.

Overall, the difference in verb choice makes *crossing one's mind* into just a brief thought - it comes and then goes - whethers *enter*, just means that a thought has gone into your mind but not out again.

Comment: I think @Hot Licks is right to say that in *most* contexts they're pretty much interchangeable, but I agree with you that *sometimes* there can be a difference in that thoughts which *enter* your mind might be more likely to *stay* within your conscious awareness than thoughts which merely *cross* your mind. But I also think that "solutions" are more likely to *cross,* whereas "unwelcome thoughts" are more likely to *enter*. Arguably you won't forget the former if they *do* occur to you, but actually they're both more likely to occur in *negated* contexts, so "duration" doesn't really apply.

Comment: @FumbleFingers That sounds about right, could you suggest an edit that covers that?

Comment: My first attempt to gather supporting evidence [from Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22it+never+crossed+my+mind+that%22) reveals that *it crossed my mind that...* is apparently twice as common as the negated *it never crossed my mind that...* On the other hand, negated *it never **entered** my mind that...* is four times more common that the non-negated version. I'm not quite sure where that leaves us.

Answer (score 0):

They are interchangeable.

By the way, your second example works better than your first.  It's kind of complicated.  I personally (as a Spanish speaker) would go into a whole thing about the subjunctive.  Maybe someone else would have a different way of explaining it.  I will write it up as a question for the grammar experts to have some fun with.