# Is subjunctive the correct description for what's going on in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, subjunctive-mood

In this [question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/353520/cross-ones-mind-and-enter-ones-mind), two examples were given:

> 1. It never crosses my mind that he is lying to me.
> 2. It never crosses my mind that we might lose.

I believe that #2 works better than #1, and that #1 could be fixed by changing "is lying" to "might" or "would".

Why?  What's going on, grammatically?  I think it has something to do with the subjunctive, but maybe my understanding of Spanish grammar doesn't carry over to this as well as I imagine.